# How to hide the column 1 with serial no

Tags: r, dt

How can we hide the first column which has the serial no. in a R [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).I wouldnt like to hardcode select specific columns . Is there any other options which I can use.

Comment: In the link you provided, it is mentioned `rownames = FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Set `rownames = FALSE`

```
datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE)
```